# Replace every character occurence but last

Tags: java

Lets say I have a string of `a.b.c.d`. How do I write a method which will transform that string into `abc.d` ? Or is there any method available implementation out there ?

What I have tried so far

```
        int dotPlacing = propertyName.lastIndexOf(".");//12
        String modString = propertyName.replace(".", "");
        modString = modString.substring(0, dotPlacing-1) + "."+modString.substring(dotPlacing-1);
```

I am using that for writing Hibernate criteria. It works for `user.country.name` but not for `user.country.name.ss`. Havent tried for any other strings.

Comment: Are you doing this for file extensions or a more general use?

Comment: Lesson learnt, should have posted what I have in the question. Thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can extract substring form 0 to `lastIndexOf('.')`. In this substring replace all `.` to empty string. After that merge with subtring (from `lastIndexOf .` to end).

Something like:

```
String theString = "a.b.c.d";

String separator = ".";
String replacement = "";
String newString = theString.substring(0, theString.lastIndexOf(separator)).replaceAll(separator , replacement).concat(theString.substring(theString.lastIndexOf(separator)));

Assert.assertEquals("abc.d", newString);
```

Comment: Excellent. What didn't I think of that !

Answer (score 7):

```
  String start = "a.b.c.d.wea.s";
  String regex = "\\.(?=.*\\.)";
  String end = start.replaceAll(regex, "");
  System.out.println(end);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `dotPlacing` not on your original string but on new string that doesn't have any dots so its length has changes, which is main reason of your problems.

Change your code to

```
int dotPlacing = propertyName.lastIndexOf('.');

String modString = propertyName.substring(0, dotPlacing).replace(".","")
        + propertyName.substring(dotPlacing);
System.out.println(modString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use StringTokenizer

```
String in = "a.b.c.d";

StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(in,".");
String last = "",result = "";
while(t.hasMoreTokens())
{
    last = t.nextToken();
    result += " "+last;
}
result = result.trim();
result.replaceAll(last,"."+last);
```